# awk print multiple column file into single column

Tags: awk

My file looks like that:

> 315
>   717
>   461 737
>   304
>   440
>   148 206 264 322 380 438 496
>   801
>   495
>   355
>   249 989
>   768
>   946

I want to print all those columns in a single column file (one long first column).

If I try to

`awk '{print $1}'> new_file;`
`awk '{print $2}' >> new_file`

There are white spaces in between. How to solve this thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use something like:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i }' file
```

For each line, iterate through columns, and print each column in a new line.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a bit cryptic:

```
awk '1' RS='[[:space:]]+' inputfile
```

It says "print every record, treating any whitespace as record separators".

Answer (score 3):

You don't need as much as `sed` for this: just translate spaces to newlines

```
tr ' ' '\n' < file
```

`tr` is purely a filter, so you have to redirect a file into it.

Answer (score 1):

A `perl` solution:

```
perl -pe 's/\s+(?=\S)/\n/g' infile
```

Output:

```
315
717
461
737
304
440
148
206
264
322
380
438
496
801
495
355
249
989
768
946
```